# Connecting WordPress to remote database using IPV6

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mariadb, ipv6

I am trying to connect WordPress to a remote MariaDB database using an IPV6 address. When I input all of the information, WordPress returns "Error establishing a database connection".

The servers are definitely connecting to each other correctly, I am able to use MYSQL Client to connect to the database using the credentials, and I am even able to install Joomla using the credentials, just not WordPress. If it helps, Joomla will only install when using MYSQLi, not MYSQL (PDO). We have tried changing the MariaDB bind address to the IPV6 and also tried this as "::", but WordPress still does not connect through IPV6.

WordPress will connect using an IPV4 address, just not IPV6. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try using hostnames instead of addresses. Depending on the syntax the colon in IPv6 addresses might be confused with the colon often used to specify a port number. If that is the case then putting squares brackets around the IPv6 address (like "[2001:db8::1]") might help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you explain what you mean by using hostnames? In regards to putting the square brackets around the IPv6 address, I tried it both with and without the brackets and neither worked.

Comment: A hostname would be the FQDN of the server, for example: server1.yourserver.com

Comment: Have you made sure to allow the remote database to have access using the wordpress user?

Comment: We wouldn't be able to use hostnames because we're using the IPv6 on a private network. On the database itself, we have changed the bind address to the IPv6 address and we have configured the WordPress user on the database to access remotely, this is why Joomla connects to the database.